# How to remove letterboxing on XS Max App -

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview, swift5

App loads fullscreen on all of the emulators.  When I load it onto my iPhone X it is full screen.  However on my wife's XS Max I get the below letterboxing.  Please help!

[XS Max Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFpx8.png)

Here is my code.  This is a VERY simple WebView app.

**AppDelegate**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    window = UIWindow()
    window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
    return true
}

}
```

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

// MARK: - Lifecycle Methods
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupUI()
    let myURL = URL(string: "https://cotta.work")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

// MARK: - Properties
lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return webView
}()

}

extension ViewController {
func setupUI() {
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        webView.topAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
        webView.leftAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
        webView.bottomAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
        webView.rightAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor)
    ])
}

}
```

Comment: Because you have no LaunchScreen.storyboard?

Comment: That's because you are not setting the top and the bottom of the web view to the safe area.

Comment: I setup my launch with the plist.info.  Of course that isn't working either.  Just getting a white screen.  Do I need to create the LaunchScreen.storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set root view controller like that, this is for AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    window = UIWindow()
    let controller = ViewController()
    window?.rootViewController = controller
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
    return true
}
```

This is for SceneDelegate:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    let controller = ViewController()
    window.rootViewController = controller
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

after that set your view controller:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return webView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupUI()
    guard let myURL = URL(string: "https://cotta.work") else {return}
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}

func setupUI() {
    view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
 }
}
```

naturally if you present rootViewController in Scene delegate, delete presentation in AppDelegate...

Comment: My project doesn't have a SceneDelegate.swift file.  Can I just create it and place the provided code inside?

Comment: @DigitalCardinal write it in AppDelegate under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions like your original project...

Comment: I did the two steps I could.  I don't have a SceneDelegate file.  The project builds ok and loads fine.  However my launch scene isn't filling the screen.  Its just the size of the X series and attached to the top left corner.  Other than that this works well.

Comment: @DigitalCardinal the code goes or on AppDelegate or in SceneDelegate, if you don't have SceneDelegate put it on AppDelegate... For launch screen i don't understand well what is the problem...what's in yours launchScreen.storyboard?

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I added the func scene to the AppDelegate.  The WebView seems to be working well.  The LauncScreen.storyboard is basically two images.  A BG and a Logo.  However it isn't resizing to fit various devices.  Here is a screenshot of an iPad.  For large screens (ipad) its too small and not stretching.  On smaller phones (iPhone 8) its too big and hangs off edge of screen.  [link](https://ibb.co/cxbgXVV)

Comment: @DigitalCardinal Have you set constraints in launch screen?